# How to convert for loop into while loop in LEX?

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, yacc, lex, lexical-analysis

I am stuck at a program where I have to convert `“for-loop”/“do-while loop”` to `“while loop”` without changing the meaning of the program. There may be loops inside loops and so on. The input would be a C
language program and output would be a valid C language program.

The solution I got so far is to read a C program from a file and if I detect a for statement, I take the initializer out and replace `"for"` with `"while"`.

But I am not getting as to how to do it.

Comment: This isn't something that you'd handle at the lexical analysis level, but rather in the parser or as an AST->AST transformation after parsing.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint, a for loop consists of an initializer, a condition and an updater

```
`for (initializationStatement; testExpression; updateStatement)
    {
        // statements inside the body of loop
    }`
```

you would need something like

```
initializationStatement;
while( testExpression ) {

    updateStatement;
}
```

Comment: I feel like OP is asking how to implement this transformation, not what the result should be.

Comment: @sepp2k Yes, I was asking for its implementation.

Comment: How will I implement this in my lex code? What should I write inside this regex %% _mycode_ %%

Comment: @AmberBhanarkar What you should write inside the regular expressions are the lexical rules of the C language, just like in any other C lexer. As I said in my other comment, this transformation is something you'd implement in the parser or afterwards - not in the lexer.

Comment: Sorry , is it this bit your looking for (excuse the pun) it shows more than the For loop but you can rip that bit out https://github.com/TheNilesh/lex-yacc/blob/master/loops.y